# Mirror texture paint on selected faces of an object?

Tags: texture-painting, mirror

I'm a complete noob at Blender. My character is not completely symmetrical, so when I texture paint, Blender mirrors on the arms, legs, hands and her horns (the symmetrical parts) but not the face even though it is symmetrical too.

I want to know if there is a way to mirror the face by maybe selecting the faces of the face?

[image: My UV map and character object]

Here's my blender file too:

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Question: is all of the model one object, and is the face the same object? Are you using a mirror modifier on any of it? Have you turned on X symmetry in the texture paint tool panel(it is there in the toolbar under 'symmetry')?

Comment: @CraigDJones Oh... I thought I turned on X symmetry in the texture paint tool since it was already painting symmetrically for some parts of the model, but it wasn't on. Thank you!

Comment: ok I thought you already turned it on

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

I just had to turn on X symmetry in the texture paint tool pane.